# Has there been any mathematical research on redundancy in axiom sets?

Tags: reference-request, research

This is a bit of a soft question, but has there been any significant research on redundancy in axiom sets? Let me explain what I mean. I know that a few papers deal with proving that a particular axiom is or is not redundant from a set of axioms. However, I am talking about something a little different, and more advanced. It could happen that once a particular axiom is deleted, some other axiom, which was also redundant from the original set, is now non-redundant. Let me give a concrete example. Take the set of axioms that characterize strict partial orders. The three axioms are Anti-reflexivity, Asymmetry, and Transitivity. In this set, Anti-reflexivity and Asymmetry are, individually, redundant, but if either one is deleted the other axiom becomes non-redundant. It could also happen that once a redundant axiom is deleted, some other axiom which was also redundant from the original set is still redundant from the original set. So, has there been any research into this type of question? I would like some references for this.

Comment: Once you start dropping axioms you get "systems" [for lack of a better word] which may or may not be interesting to study in their own right.

Comment: There are plenty of cases where individual axioms are shown to be independent of the others by constructing two examples which satisfy the other axioms, one satisfying the particular axiom and the other not.  Until this is done, there is always the suspicion that an axiom is redundant.

Comment: So basically, you're looking for cases where $A\equiv B$ is a theorem of $T\land C$ but neither $A\to B$ nor $B\to A$ is a theorem of $T$, and $T\land A\land C$ and $T\land A\land B$ are both theories of interest.